# Converting a TCHAR to wstring

Tags: c++

```cpp
TCHAR path[_MAX_PATH+1]; 
std::wstring ws(&path[0], sizeof(path)/sizeof(path[0]));
```

or

```cpp
TCHAR path[_MAX_PATH]; 
std::wstring ws(&path[0]);
```

While converting a `TCHAR` to `wstring`  both are correct?

I'm asking just for clarification, I'm in doubt if I'm converting it correctly.

Comment: The latter will have an issue if `path` does not contain a null termination character `'\0'` within the first `_MAX_PATH` characters, then it will likely access out of bounds and generate a runtime error

Comment: @CoryKramer And about the second option? is it correct?

Comment: Purely based on the code you show, neither one is correct, since path is not initialized. 
Assuming that path has been filled with correct data I would just use std::wstring ws(path). So the important detail is who fills path and with what, there must be at least a trailing zero in that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is problematic in several ways.

First, `std::wstring` is a string of `wchar_t` (aka `WCHAR`) while `TCHAR` may be either `CHAR` or `WCHAR`, depending on configuration. So either use `WCHAR` and `std::wstring`, or `TCHAR` and `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` (remembering that `std::wstring` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<WCHAR>`).

Second, the problem is with string length. This snippet:

```
WCHAR path[_MAX_PATH];
std::wstring ws(&path[0], sizeof(path)/sizeof(path[0]));
```

will create a string of length exactly `_MAX_PATH + 1`, plus a terminating null (and likely with embedded nulls, C++ strings allow that). Likely not what you want.

The other one:

```cpp
WCHAR path[_MAX_PATH+1]; 
...
std::wstring ws(&path[0]);
```

expects that `path` holds a null-terminated string by the time `ws` is constructed, and copies it into `ws`. If `path` happens to be not null-terminated, UB ensues (usually, either garbage in `ws` or access violation).

If your `path` is *either* null-terminated or contains `_MAX_PATH`-length string, I suggest using it like this:

```cpp
WCHAR path[_MAX_PATH+1];
... // fill up to _MAX_PATH characters
path[_MAX_PATH] = L'0'; // ensure it is null-terminated
std::wstring ws(path); // construct from a null-terminated string
```

Or if you know the actual length, just pass it:

```cpp
WCHAR path[_MAX_PATH];
size_t length = fill_that_path(path);
std::wstring ws(path, length); // length shouldn’t include the null terminator, if any
```

See [the docs](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) (it’s the same for `string` and `wstring` except of different char type).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of `path`. If it is an arbitrary char array that can contain null characters, then you should use the first version which explicitely gives the size. But if is contains a null terminated string (and only contains unused values after the first null), then you should use the second one which will stop on the terminating null character.